# Extracting folder from running jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, extract

How can i extract a folder from the jar I'm running? Using `new JarFile(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath())` for some reason throws me a `FileNotFoundException` with an `Access Denied` only when I'm running it from the IDE (I'm using IntelliJ IDEA).

Anyone knows an another way to solve or fix this one?

Comment: You can’t, because there is no folder.  A .jar file is a zip file, and a zip file merely has entries which each have a path-like name.  The only thing you can do is look for entries with a particular prefix.  A much better approach is to place a text file in your .jar which lists all the files you will want to extract.  You are the one building it, after all, so you know what you’re putting in it.

Comment: I don't really like this way, but if it's the only one I will follow it. Is the only?

Comment: The only other way is the [Zip File System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html).  That should let you use [Files.walk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) or [Files.list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-) to copy a “directory.”